# Error deploying Mule application in mule standalone 3.5.0

Tags: mule, esb

I run my application with the embedded server (mule server 3.5.0 CE) in anypoint studio and its deployed well but when i try to deploy it in mule standalone 3.5.0 i get this error:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New app 'pushV1'                                         +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2015-04-08 17:14:17,009 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader: [pushV1] Loading the following jars:
=============================
file:/root/Desktop/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/pushV1/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.32.jar
file:/root/Desktop/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/pushV1/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar
=============================

INFO  2015-04-08 17:14:17,009 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector: Found logging config for application 'pushV1' at 'file:/root/Desktop/mule-standalone-3.5.0/conf/log4j.properties'
ERROR 2015-04-08 17:14:17,648 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'pushV1', see below            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: PropertyBatchUpdateException: Failed properties: Property 'objectClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ws1/Transformer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:181)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
    at ...
```

http://pastebin.com/xvmNrxx9

Comment: Sounds like the issue is the java version you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: emm i have jre1.8.0_40 i should mention that the server where I am trying to deploy is on another machine, I don't know what version of java is installed there. that must be it the problem?!

Comment: Mule 3.5.0 does not support Java 8, there could be issues there for sure. I suggest trying with Java 7 or even 6 (since that is the version used when testing).

Comment: I am lost :(. in my machine I have java 8 I deployed the application on my local server and it worked well. I thought I have to install the same version of java on the other machine or is my mule server. iF MULE 3.5.0 don't support java 8 why my application worked well in my machine.

Comment: It's not supported but it could work (depending on what modules you use for example), it just wasn't tested properly. And as was mentioned below, it also depends on the Java version you are using in Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the version which you are compiling the source code in the IDE... looks like you are using java 8.

After that, check which version is using your mule-standalone-server.

Comment: How can i check the version Java in the IDE?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the java version in Anypoint Studio like below
Go to--> Window-->Click on Preferences-->double click on java--> click on installed JREs

Then  you can update java 7 or 8 if it is there in your system